# big query conversion from string to date format

Tags: google-bigquery

I have string dates that I need converted to the date format. How do I take dates like "Jan 1, 2012 12:40:17 AM" and convert it to 1/1/2012? It doesn't work when I try to cast it as a date or when I use the date function.

Answer (score 0):

Try (*play with*) below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 'Jan 1, 2012 12:40:17 AM' AS dt
)
SELECT 
  dt, 
  PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %r', dt) AS dt_as_timestamp,
  DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %r', dt)) AS dt_as_date, 
  FORMAT_DATE('%m/%d/%Y',  DATE(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%b %d, %Y %r', dt))) AS dt_as_string
FROM yourTable
```

see more